# Python - List elements being overwritten somehow

Tags: python, list, recursion, append

I have a recursive function that tries to find combinations of numbers that add to a certain number. I store the results in a list called    `validCombinations`

The code:

```
sum = 4
digits = 2
currentDigit = digits
validCombinations = [] 

#recursion function to find combinations of numbers that add to the sum variable
def recursive(index):
    if 10 not in digitList:        
        if index >= 0:
            total = 0
            for n in digitList:
                total += n
            if total == sum:
                validCombinations.append(digitList)
            digitList[index] += 1
            recursive(index-1)
        else:
            recursive(currentDigit-1)

digitList = []

for n in range(digits,0,-1):
    for i in range(n):
        digitList.append(0)
    recursive(n-1)
    digitList = []
    currentDigit -= 1

print validCombinations
```

When running this it outputs

```
[[9, 10], [10, 0]]
```

When i expect to see this

```
[[2, 2], [4]]
```

I have stepped through the code and it seems like it is somehow overwriting the elements in the list, however in my code I only ever interact with `validCombinations` by using the `append()` method, which should just add it to the end.

Am I missing something or is the recursion causing this?

Comment: is `digits` supposed to be the lower bounds for numbers that should be tested?

Comment: look at what's happening here: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7cbd68961bc0b577a15f

Comment: We are not  expecting [1,3] as a valid decomposition of 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use list:

```
        if total == sum:
            validCombinations.append(list(digitList))
```

You have to get a copy of digitList, not digitList.